# Correct command to convert colors for all images recursively with ImageMagick

Tags: linux, bash, macos, imagemagick

I found a command on another thread that works perfectly for converting a specific color to a transparent color which I've tested on one directory.  However I have many images in different direcorties that I need to do this to.  The file structure cannot change, ideally the command will simply replace the current image with the old one.  As the command runs now it creates a new file in the /batch directory.

```
for file in *.png ; do convert "${file}" -transparent '#bbb7b9' "batch/${file}" ; done
```

So the two modifications to this command would be:

**1) The command executes recursively**

**2) The original image is replaced with the new one (with the same filename)**

I've researched and found that using the `find` command may be what I need but I'm confused about how to translate this over from the `for` command...  It looks like some variation of -exec may be what I need but I haven't found anything that works.

Thoughts/Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can use the mogrify command to process a whole folder of images (no automatic recursing to subdirectories).

```
cd to your image directory
mogrify -format png -transparent '#bbb7b9' *.png
```

However, I would suggest either creating a new directory to hold your output images or creating a backup copy of your input directory, so that you do not make a mistake and write over your images with bad copies.

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Comment: This doesn't run through all the sub directories though.  I did find a solution mixing your command with my initial idea of using the find command.  The command ends up being: `find . -name '*.png' -exec magick mogrify -transparent '#bbb7b9' *.png {} +`

Comment: Correct. Mogrify only process files in one directory and does not recurse to subdirectories. So you have to loop over each sub director. The way you have done it is one way